# javascript bind object in event creation

Tags: javascript, html, events, bind

I'm actually getting stuck on a simple (pretty sure it is) example.

```
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>
<script>
    var JSClass = {
        element : null,
        click : function() {
            console.log(this.element.id);
        },
        created : function(element) {
            this.element = element;
            this.element.addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this));
        }
    };
    JSClass.created(document.querySelector('#first'));
    JSClass.created(document.querySelector('#second'));
</script>
```

By binding the entire object when I create the event I should obtain "first" when I click on the first element and "second" when I click on the second element but it's not the case.
It's fully functional for other objects I use but this simple case doesn't work...

Comment: There's just one object involved. When you call `.created()` the second time, it overwrites the value of the "element" property that was set when you called it the first time.

Comment: Change `JSClass` to a function which returns the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `class`, set `this.element` to `element` passed to constructor

```html
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>
<script>
  class JSClass {
    constructor(element) {
      this.element = element;
    }
    created() {
      this.element
        .addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this));
    }
    click() {
      console.log(this.element.id);
    }
  };
  let first = new JSClass(document.querySelector('#first'));
  let second = new JSClass(document.querySelector('#second'));
  first.created();
  second.created();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the best modern way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your object to behave like a class, you can make use of function closures like this:

```js
var JSClass = function(element) {
  this.element = element;
  element.addEventListener('click', click.bind(this)); 
  
  function click() {
    console.log(this.element.id);
  }
};

new JSClass(document.querySelector('#first'));
new JSClass(document.querySelector('#second'));
```

```html
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't creating a class, you are creating an object.

So each time you call `.created` on that object, you are overwriting the element inside.

Try using `Object.create` to make two different objects

```
var JSClass = {
    element : null,
    click : function() {
        console.log(this.element.id);
    },
    created : function(element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.element.addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this));
    }
};

var first = Object.create(JSClass);
var second = Object.create(JSClass);

first.created(document.querySelector('#first'));
second.created(document.querySelector('#second'));
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcdgjuaL/)

Comment: You're right about the "class" vs "object". It's a mistake from my side. Along my description I only speak about objects and the name of my object is JSClass ;)